# d3.js creating text arcs

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a set of curved text arcs. When I try and and put the text in circle it doesn't show up. I am also unsure of how to control the orientation of the text.

Is there a more sophisticated way of building this - also need to hide the original text - not sure if I want to put the text inside another data attribute

```
<div data-type="curve">some text that needs</div>

function curveme(el){

    var content = $(el).text();

    //Create the SVG
    var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
            .attr("width", 400)
            .attr("height", 120);


    //Create an SVG path            
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", "wavy") //very important to give the path element a unique ID to reference later
        .attr("d", "M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70 Q 340,140 400,30") //Notation for an SVG path, from bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2565344
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke", "#AAAAAA");


    /*
    var pi = Math.PI;

    var arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(150)
            .outerRadius(180)
            .startAngle(0)
            .endAngle(pi/2)

    svg.append("path")
            .attr("d", arc)
            .attr("id", "wavy")
            .attr("transform", "translate(200,200)")
            .style("fill","none")
            .style("stroke", "#AAAAAA");
    */

    //Create an SVG text element and append a textPath element
    svg.append("text")
       .append("textPath") //append a textPath to the text element
        .attr("xlink:href", "#wavy") //place the ID of the path here
        .style("text-anchor","middle") //place the text halfway on the arc
        .attr("startOffset", "50%")     
        .text(content);
}



$('[data-type="curve"]').each(function(index) {
    curveme(this);
});
```

Comment: can you please provide a link to a working example?

Answer (score 0):

The only part of your question that is answer-able is:

> also need to hide the original text

Just change to:

```
function curveme(el) {
  var obj = $(el);
  var content = obj.text();
  obj.text("");
```

---

Your other questions:

> When I try and and put the text in circle it doesn't show up

What does this mean? Your path is a circle and it won't work?  Replicate your problem with code.

> I am also unsure of how to control the orientation of the text.

What does this mean? Start aligned left? Right? Vertical?

> Is there a more sophisticated way of building this?

Yes, no, maybe.  What's sophisticated to you?  This is subject to opinion and is not suitable for stackoverflow.

Here's [your code running](http://plnkr.co/edit/T7rYVLJJZVavy2JUlGXj?p=preview) if you want to add on to it.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to focus on other aspects of the site at the time. I've managed to resolve the issues.

---

"also need to hide the original text"
^ I acquire the text and then just empty the div

"When I try and and put the text in circle it doesn't show up"
^ it wasn't translated correctly

"I am also unsure of how to control the orientation of the text."
^ I was wondering what aspect of the code controls the orientation of the text to avoid it appearing upside down or if it sticks to the inside rim or outside.

"Is there a more sophisticated way of building this?"
^ I think I have an issue with the way you have to link to the arcs and text sections together.

```
function getRandomNumber(s, e){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * e) + s;
}

function curveme(el,index){

    var content = $(el).text();
    $(el).empty();

    var markerPointerSize = $(el).parent().find('.markerpointer').width();

    var diameter = markerPointerSize+32;

    //var diameter = 195;//large
    //var diameter = 125;//small
    radius = diameter/2;

    //Create the SVG
    var svg = d3.select(el).append("svg")
            .attr("width", diameter)
            .attr("height", diameter);

    var pi = Math.PI;

    var arc = d3.arc()
            .innerRadius(radius-20)
            .outerRadius(radius-15)
            .startAngle(getRandomNumber(-1, 0.5))
            .endAngle(pi);

    //Create an SVG path            
    svg.append("path")
        .attr("id", "wavy"+index) //very important to give the path element a unique ID to reference later
        .attr("d", arc)
        .attr("transform", "translate("+radius+","+radius+")")
        .style("fill", "none");

    //Create an SVG text element and append a textPath element
    svg.append("text")
       .append("textPath") //append a textPath to the text element
        .attr("xlink:href", "#wavy"+index) //place the ID of the path here
        .style("text-anchor","right") //place the text right on the arc
        .attr("startOffset", "0")       
        .text(content);
}


$('[data-type="curve"]').each(function(index) {
    curveme(this,index);
});
```